# What is the correct way to use vue component libraries?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, laravel-8, vuejs3

I am trying to use some external vue component libraries in a Laravel project but my first few attempts with vue-avatar, vue notification bell and pwa-install have all been unsuccessful.

With the first two, everything appears to check out, there're no build errors and the components actually get displayed in the html, but without the avatar or notification bell. There's no indication that the external packages where imported into my components.

These were the steps I took:

1. npm install of vue-avatar and notification-bell as required.
2. I created a component for each, imported the installed each package and did a default export.
3. I then utilised my component in another file as normal.

The codes are basically boilerplate with nothing to add so I'm at a loss as to why I didn't get the expected output.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is my avatar component code:

```
<template>
  <div></div>
</template>

<script>
import Avatar from 'vue-avatar'

export default {
    components: {
        Avatar
    }
}
</script>
```

And this is the code of the layout file where I used it:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="min-h-screen bg-gray-100">
            <nav class="bg-white border-b border-gray-100">
                <!-- Primary Navigation Menu -->
                <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                    <div class="flex justify-between h-16">
                        <div class="flex">
                            <!-- Logo -->
                            <div class="flex-shrink-0 flex items-center">
                                <inertia-link :href="route('dashboard')">
                                    <breeze-application-logo class="block h-9 w-auto" />
                                </inertia-link>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Navigation Links -->
                            <div class="hidden space-x-8 sm:-my-px sm:ml-10 sm:flex">
                                <breeze-nav-link :href="route('dashboard')" :active="route().current('dashboard')">
                                    Dashboard
                                </breeze-nav-link>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div v-if="$page.props.flash.message" class="alert">
                            {{ $page.props.flash.message }}
                        </div>
                        <!-- <div>
                        <broadcast-message></broadcast-message>
                        </div>  -->
                        <avatar :username="$page.props.auth.user.first_name"></avatar>
                        <notification-bell />
                        <div class="hidden sm:flex sm:items-center sm:ml-6">
                            <!-- Settings Dropdown -->
                            <div class="ml-3 relative">
                                <breeze-dropdown align="right" width="48">
                                    <template #trigger>
                                        <span class="inline-flex rounded-md">
                                            <button type="button" class="inline-flex items-center px-3 py-2 border border-transparent text-sm leading-4 font-medium rounded-md text-gray-500 bg-white hover:text-gray-700 focus:outline-none transition ease-in-out duration-150">
                                                {{ $page.props.auth.user.first_name }}

                                                <svg class="ml-2 -mr-0.5 h-4 w-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
                                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                                                </svg>
                                            </button>
                                        </span>
                                    </template>

                                    <template #content>
                                        <breeze-dropdown-link :href="route('logout')" method="post" as="button">
                                            Log Out
                                        </breeze-dropdown-link>
                                    </template>
                                </breeze-dropdown>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Hamburger -->
                        <div class="-mr-2 flex items-center sm:hidden">
                            <button @click="showingNavigationDropdown = ! showingNavigationDropdown" class="inline-flex items-center justify-center p-2 rounded-md text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-500 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">
                                <svg class="h-6 w-6" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                    <path :class="{'hidden': showingNavigationDropdown, 'inline-flex': ! showingNavigationDropdown }" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
                                    <path :class="{'hidden': ! showingNavigationDropdown, 'inline-flex': showingNavigationDropdown }" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
                                </svg>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Responsive Navigation Menu -->
                <div :class="{'block': showingNavigationDropdown, 'hidden': ! showingNavigationDropdown}" class="sm:hidden">
                    <div class="pt-2 pb-3 space-y-1">
                        <breeze-responsive-nav-link :href="route('dashboard')" :active="route().current('dashboard')">
                            Dashboard
                        </breeze-responsive-nav-link>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Responsive Settings Options -->
                    <div class="pt-4 pb-1 border-t border-gray-200">
                        <div class="flex items-center px-4">
                            <div class="font-medium text-base text-gray-800">{{ $page.props.auth.user.first_name }}</div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mt-3 space-y-1">
                            <breeze-responsive-nav-link :href="route('logout')" method="post" as="button">
                                Log Out
                            </breeze-responsive-nav-link>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <!-- Page Heading -->
            <header class="bg-white shadow" v-if="$slots.header">
                <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-6 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                    <slot name="header" />
                </div>
            </header>

            <!-- Page Content -->
            <main>
                <slot />
            </main>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import BreezeApplicationLogo from '@/Components/ApplicationLogo'
    import BreezeDropdown from '@/Components/Dropdown'
    import BreezeDropdownLink from '@/Components/DropdownLink'
    import BreezeNavLink from '@/Components/NavLink'
    import BreezeResponsiveNavLink from '@/Components/ResponsiveNavLink'
    //import BroadcastMessage from '@/Components/BroadcastMessage'
    import Avatar from '@/Components/DashboardAvatar'
    import NotificationBell from '@/Components/DashboardNotificationBell'
    export default {
        props: {
            username: String,
        },

        components: {
            BreezeApplicationLogo,
            BreezeDropdown,
            BreezeDropdownLink,
            BreezeNavLink,
            BreezeResponsiveNavLink,
            //BroadcastMessage,
            Avatar,
            NotificationBell,
        },

        data() {
            return {
                showingNavigationDropdown: false,
            }
        },
      }
</script>
```

Following your inputs, I tried to use the import in my component as suggested but I got a 'maximum call stack exceeded' error in console. See my new code:

```
<template>
  <avatar :username="username"/>
</template>

<script>
import Avatar from 'vue-avatar'

export default {
    props: {
        username: String
    },

    name: 'DashboardAvatar',

    components: {
        Avatar
    }
}
</script>
```

When I imported and used it directly, I got a type error 'cannot read property _c of undefined.

I corrected an error in my component: `<avatar :username="username" />` not `<dashboard-avatar>`  and the error is now the same type error as using the component directly that I referred to above.

Comment: This post already has an accepted answer. It cannot be *answered more*.. Open a new question or simply google the error - somebody could have made the same mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vue components directly, at least until you reach their limit and add some customization or whatever you feel like. You don't have to create a component for that component.

Your template for that component is just an empty div.
If you want to create a component for the component you should use it, not just import it. I'm a tiny bit rusty on Vue but I'm sure you can do this for the template instead:

```html
<template>
  <Avatar someAttribute="value" />
</template>
```

But you can just as well import the avatar component and use `<Avatar>` where you need it directly.

Creating a component like you did is useful for passing default parameters if you want to have some app-wide attributes you don't want to repeat. In this case you should also forward props to that component so it stays customizable for others.

Comment: I believe both responses correctly answer the question I asked even though I'm now faced with another issue as a result.

Comment: Yes I was answering at the same time as Thomas. You can always open another question (or maybe go through some Vue tutorials first?)

Comment: Thanks @Peter, I've been through some tutorials and the documentation but I'll give the docs another read and get more tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might misunderstand how Vue SFCs work.

You are importing the avatar component, but aren't actually using it.

A correct way would be for example:

```
<template>
  <avatar v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners"/>
</template>

<script>
import Avatar from 'vue-avatar'

export default {
    name:'Avatar',
    components: {
        Avatar
    }
}
</script>
```

This way you import the component from vue-avatar, and actually use it in the Avatar SFC, ($attrs and $listeners just bind all properties and events to the component). Once you have done this, your import should work.

Or you can simply import it directly in the parent component without creating a child component first (since you aren't customising the vue-avatar functionality but are just using what comes out of the box):

```
<script>
    import BreezeApplicationLogo from '@/Components/ApplicationLogo'
    import BreezeDropdown from '@/Components/Dropdown'
    import BreezeDropdownLink from '@/Components/DropdownLink'
    import BreezeNavLink from '@/Components/NavLink'
    import BreezeResponsiveNavLink from '@/Components/ResponsiveNavLink'
    //import BroadcastMessage from '@/Components/BroadcastMessage'
    import Avatar from 'vue-avatar' <----------------------Use the module here directly.
    import NotificationBell from '@/Components/DashboardNotificationBell'
    export default {
        props: {
            username: String,
        },

        components: {
            BreezeApplicationLogo,
            BreezeDropdown,
            BreezeDropdownLink,
            BreezeNavLink,
            BreezeResponsiveNavLink,
            //BroadcastMessage,
            Avatar,
            NotificationBell,
        },
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you both for your inputs. I remember importing and using the component directly without any success. I have now tried both ways again without any success and I will now edit my question to show the outcomes.

Comment: Is it possible to attach a screenshot of the console errors? If yes, how?

Comment: using v-bind="$attrs" gave the same output as the code I added. Using v-on="$listeners" showed a deprecation notice in the editor so I removed it.